# Julia: Question about variable binding, mutating, and mutable functions

Tags: recursion, julia, mutable, mutation, mutual-recursion

I am writing code in Julia which collects some output from a function `foo` (which mutates its input argument), and I'm trying to append the recursive evaluations from this function in an array `A`.

For instance, `foo!(x)` changes the value of `x` by adding `1` to each of its elements.

```
function foo!(x)
    x .= x .+ 1
    return(x)
end


julia> x = [1, 1];

julia> foo!(x);

julia> x
2-element Array{Int64,1}:
 2
 2
```

I want to create an array `A` which stores the value of `x = f(x)` over a fixed range. However, `A` just ends up containing multiple copies of the final value of `f(x)`, e.g.,

```
julia> x = [1, 1];

julia> A = [x];

julia> for i=1:3
           push!(A, foo!(x))
       end

julia> A
4-element Array{Array{Int64,1},1}:
 [4, 4]
 [4, 4]
 [4, 4]
 [4, 4]
```

I'm trying to get it to get it to efficiently output something similar to

```
julia> B
4-element Array{Array{Int64,1},1}:
 [1, 1]
 [2, 2]
 [3, 3]
 [4, 4]
```

I haven't been able to find a helpful resources for a developing a solid understanding of mutations, or the order in which mutations are executed in Julia. Any help in this regard would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Aside: It is idiomatic to write `return x` instead of `return(x)`, since `return` isn't a function, but a keyword.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you've written it, you repeatedly `push!` the same object into `A`, which your `foo!` function mutates:

```
julia> x = [1, 1]
2-element Vector{Int64}:
 1
 1

julia> A = [x]
1-element Vector{Vector{Int64}}:
 [1, 1]

julia> foo!(x)
2-element Vector{Int64}:
 2
 2

julia> A
1-element Vector{Vector{Int64}}:
 [2, 2]
```

One way of fixing this is to `copy` the elements in `A` before `x` gets mutated:

```
julia> for i ∈ 1:3
           A[i] = copy(x)
           push!(A, foo!(x))
       end

julia> A
4-element Vector{Vector{Int64}}:
 [1, 1]
 [2, 2]
 [3, 3]
 [4, 4]
```

A classic read on values vs. bindings can be found [here](https://www.juliabloggers.com/values-vs-bindings-the-map-is-not-the-territory-3/).

Comment: Thank you very much for the reference and the solution! This worked like a charm (using `deepcopy()` in my final implementation), and I have accepted the answer.

Answer (score 1):

By using only `push!` you are just creating an array of references to a single array (ie `x`). This is why you see the same value repeated many times.

If you want to keep copies of the value of `x` across invocations of `foo!` you can use `copy`:

```
julia> foo!(x) = x .+= 1
foo! (generic function with 1 method)

julia> x = [0,0];

julia> A = [copy(foo!(x)) for i in 1:4]
4-element Vector{Vector{Int64}}:
 [1, 1]
 [2, 2]
 [3, 3]
 [4, 4]
```

Comment: Thank you very much @David. This fixed it!